# How to call function in ng-click which is defined in factory service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-services

How can I call the function in ng-click which is defined inside a factory service,

```
app.factory('MyFactory', [function () {
    return {
        setTest: function(test) {
            alert(test);
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope','MyFactory', function ($scope, MyFactory) {

}]);


<li><a href="#" ng-click="setTest('PHP')">PHP</a></li>
<li><a href="#" ng-click="setTest('Javascript')">Javascript</a></li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method should be defined on your scope for it to be usable in bindings. In your controller you can

`$scope.setTest=myFactory.setTest;`

Comment: Now I am doing like this, is there any other method without defining in controller?

Comment: No, bindings are evaluated in context of the current scope.

Comment: The only way it's to put in a run block $parentScope.setTest=myFactory.setTest; but it's bad practice