# onclick="AuthorityCheck({{meeting.people}})", expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble with sending `{{meeting.people}}` value to JS function. Code is following

Error message says: Expected identifier, string or number. `{{meeting.people}}` is plain text.

Link:

```
<li class=" seriesblock ms-ContentAccent1-bgColor" ng-repeat="meeting in meetings | SeriesTitleFilter:filterString" >
    <a id="meetingItem_{{meeting.id}}" onclick="AuthorityCheck({{meeting.people}})" href="Meeting.aspx?seriesId={{meeting.id}}"></a>
</li>
```

JS function:

```
function AuthorityCheck(people){
                var ppl = people;
            }
```

Note, that `meetingItem_{{meeting.id}}` works correctly.

Any ideas, how could I fix this problem?

Comment: what library are the placeholders handled by? Handlebars, jquery templates...? Please add the appropriate tag to the question. Also what does your meeting object look like? I suspect you are trying to serialize a javascript object, as opposed to just a number like `meeting.id`.

Comment: It should use angularJS library. When i changed `meeting.id` to `meeting.people`, then it still worked for `id=""`.

Comment: you might just need to use [`ng-click=""`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick) instead on `onclick=""`

Comment: But can I use ng-click with just javascript as well? I need to check, if current person exists in meeting.people.

Comment: Try removing the braclets from `onclick="AuthorityCheck({{meeting.people}})"` to `onclick="AuthorityCheck(meeting.people)"`. Also change from `href` to `ng-href`.

Comment: removing for `onclick` didn't work, `meeting` nor `people` were defined. `href` works correctly as it is! :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular doesn't like mixing html event handlers with templates. You will need to use `ng-click` which calls a `$scope` method aliasing `AuthorityCheck`,. similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22318993/1901857):

```js
function AuthorityCheck(p) {
    alert(p);
    event.returnValue = false;
}

var meetingApp = angular.module('meetingApp', []);

meetingApp.controller('meetingCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.meetings = [
        { 'id': 1, people: 'fred' },
        { 'id': 2, people: 'bob' }
    ];

    // set the alias as a scope method
    $scope.meetingClick = AuthorityCheck;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="meetingApp">
    <div ng-controller="meetingCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li class="seriesblock ms-ContentAccent1-bgColor" ng-repeat="meeting in meetings">
                <a id="meetingItem_{{meeting.id}}" ng-click="meetingClick(meeting.people)" href="Meeting.aspx?seriesId={{meeting.id}}">{{meeting.people}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```